# How do I "import" a HTML file from a shared drive into a JSP from my war file?

Tags: java, html, jsp

Preface: I am an inexperienced java programmer handed one of his first assignments.  If I do not ask the question correctly or do not give enough detail, please let me know.

I am trying to import a HTML page that is saved on my C drive.  I am trying to import it to the content portion (div id="content") of a JSP file that exists in a war file.  I have already figured out that I can not use jsp:include, #include, @include file because the file exists outside the war file.  I also figured out that c:import and iFrame do not work.

My goal is to make the contents of the html file that is saved in on my c drive appear in the contents of the jsp (visible on the web page).

Am I on the right track with this `<% File f = new File("c:\\temp\\filename.html").......%>`

I have searched stackoverflow and the only topic that came close was "How to Include a file outside the application (war) using jsp include."  It did not really get me where I needed to go.  Maybe the answer is right in front of me but I couldnt see it.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If the html file is outside the war it is quite unsafe and might even be moved/deleted etc.

Comment: This was the instruction.  The idea is that the contents can be made updatable by few. They would access the HTML file from a shared drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP/JSTL does not offer tags which support this. You'd need to do it using pure Java. You just have to write it to the response yourself.

Here's one of the simplest ways:

```
<%
    Reader reader = new FileReader("c:/path/to/external/file.html");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; (i = reader.read()) != -1;) {
            out.write(i);
        }
    } finally {
        try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
%>
```

You could wrap it in a custom tag to keep your JSP free of *scriptlet* clutter, or you could read it into a `String` in a servlet and pass it to JSP EL scope.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want clients to see the contents of `filename.html` located on your *server*? If so, why don't you just get it inside your project/war?

Or do you want clients to see the contents of a `filename.html` they have on *their* computers? If so, you might be able to just add an `iframe` with that source... but you'll run into many security-related problems, since browsers won't ordinarily let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<% File f = new File("c:\\temp\\filename.html");
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
   while (in.readLine() != null) {
     out.println(blah blah blah);          
   } 
   in.close();
%>
```

reading the File and Printing it to the JSP should work,

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to use http form upload in your jsp application. In that case your file can be in any place that is accesible in your filesystem instead of hardcoding it to be in a certain place. Usage http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Good tutorial on http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html
Some useful hints can also be found in the video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLamJlRg9Ws